# membership provider - what does it need to work?

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms-authentication

I am trying to tie my ASP .NET IDENTITY to a Membership Provider.

ASP .NET Identity requires the authentication module removed in web .config, and the authentication mode set to none.

Does Membership Provider (boxed, or custom) require any of the two to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Forms` for forms authentication.

Comment: so Forms and Membership Provider go hand in hand, there is no way out ofthis?

Comment: it is a common misconception, but these two are different.

http://brockallen.com/2012/06/04/membership-is-not-the-same-as-forms-authentication/